# I need to merge these two lists together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, spyder

```
listA = [['a','1'],['e','5'],['i','3'],['o','7'],['u','3']]
listB = [['a','6'],['b','3'],['c','4'],['d','1'],['e','2']]
```

Now, these lists represent item count. And i want to merge these two lists so that i can see the count of each item in the other list as well.

If an item is present in one list and is not present in the other list, then i want to state that as '0' rather than null. As shown below:

```
output = [['a','1','6'],['e','5','2'],['i','3','0'],['o','7','0'],
      ['u','3','0'],['b','0','3'],['c','0','4'],['d','0','1']]
```

Edit: Just to clarify the question for future reference. It has already been answered.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the *exact* rules for combining the lists. It's good that you included an example, but that's only part of it. In particular, you should explain the significance of the string containing the character `"0"`.

Comment: There is no `0` in the initial lists, how does it end up in `['i', '3', '0']`? Is that a default value?

Comment: yes, it ( "0" ) is the default count if the count does not show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
listA = [['a','1'],['e','5'],['i','3'],['o','7'],['u','3']]
listB = [['a','6'],['b','3'],['c','4'],['d','1'],['e','2']]

dictA = dict(listA)
dictB = dict(listB)

result = []

for key, value in listA:
  result.append([key, value, dictB.get(key, '0')])

for key, value in listB:
  if key not in dictA:
    result.append([key, '0', value])

print(result)
# [['a', '1', '6'], ['e', '5', '2'], ['i', '3', '0'], ['o', '7', '0'], ['u', '3', '0'], ['b', '0', '3'], ['c', '0', '4'], ['d', '0', '1']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict from collections. 
Like this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> output = defaultdict(list)

>>> for k,v in dict(listA).items():
...     output[k].append(v)
...
>>> output
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['1'], 'e': ['5'], 'i': ['3'], 'o': ['7'], 'u': ['3']})

>>> for k,v in dict(listB).items():
...     output[k].append(v)
...
>>> output
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '6'], 'e': ['5', '2'], 'i': ['3'], 'o': ['7'], 'u': ['3'], 'b': ['3'], 'c': ['4'], 'd': ['1']})

>>> [[k,*v] for k,v in output.items()]
[['a', '1', '6'], ['e', '5', '2'], ['i', '3'], ['o', '7'], ['u', '3'], ['b', '3'], ['c', '4'], ['d', '1']]
```